# Issue with Visual Studio loading a project in a folder that contains a 

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

I'm trying to open a project that has a folder called MyApp.ServiceHost and inside has a project called ServiceHost.csproj.

The folder layout is sorta like this:

```
SLN
-> Services
- -> MyApp.ServiceHost
- - -> ServiceHost.csproj 
-> MyApp.OtherStuff
```

Everytime I try to open the solution I get ".ServiceHost" is not a support project type.

Is there anyway to fix this?  It's obviously not a project.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Can you not just rename the folder in question to remove the period character?

Comment: Nope.  This is in source control worked on by 30+ developers.  I'm the only one with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Visual Web Developer installation was corrupted.  I uninstalled it and reinstalled and all is fine.